# Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x' (110)

Tags: mysql, centos6

Hello I've an issue on MySQL I can't connect to it remotely, I already looked for the answers posted here but none of them works for me!

This is the Error Message when I trying to connect to mysql

```
$> mysql -u user01 -h x.x.x.x -p
```

---

- ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x' (110)

---

**Telnet**

```
[root@machine2 ~]# telnet x.x.x.x 3306
Trying x.x.x.x...
telnet: connect to address x.x.x.x: Connection timed out
```

This the `IPTABLES` file

```
#Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Thu Jan  4 21:58:18 2018
    *filter
    :INPUT ACCEPT [56:6256]
    :FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
    :OUTPUT ACCEPT [35:3538]
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT 
    -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 3306 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
    COMMIT
#Completed on Thu Jan  4 21:58:18 2018
```

-- I already create a user

```
CREATE USER 'user' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

and this is `my.cnf` file

```
#For advice on how to change settings please see
#http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-configuration-defaults.html

[mysqld]
port=3306
skip-name-resolve
skip-external-locking
innodb_buffer_pool_size=3G



#
# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M
#
# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin
#
# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

and My port 3306 is already open

```
[root@localhost ~]# netstat -petulan
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       User       Inode      PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          12889      2056/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          13930      2441/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          13141      2133/cupsd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:32895               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      29         12977      2078/rpc.statd
tcp        0      0 x.x.x.x:22           x.x.x.x:49964        ESTABLISHED 0          7891927    4453/sshd
tcp        0     64 x.x.x.x:22           x.x.x.x:50203        ESTABLISHED 0          7892871    4482/sshd
tcp        0      0 :::3306                     :::*                        LISTEN      27         7896831    6648/mysqld
tcp        0      0 :::111                      :::*                        LISTEN      0          12892      2056/rpcbind
```

Is there something here wrong ?, thank you !

I'm using **`CentOS 6.9`**

Comment: open `my.cnf` file and define: `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` after `port` line and restart mysqld process

Comment: I already did it, is not working !

Comment: oh, try to disable firewall and also selinux and check

Comment: @num8er Light me please; how Can I do it ?

Comment: call from terminal: `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1`  on both of servers. taken from here: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=8963   or google it: or google it: https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=selinux+allow+mysql+from+remote&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=SapOWsfkAqSr8wfkqYzgBA

Comment: This is what I got : `setsebool:  SELinux is disabled.`

Comment: in which part? on db server or on client server?

Comment: @num8er  both of them

Comment: 1. try to connect from db server using: `telnet 127.0.0.1 3306`,   2. check if `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` also restart mysql if have not done after config change, 3. connect to db server from local machine using `telnet x.x.x.x 3306`    if 1, 2, 3 steps are ok, so clientside server has problems to connect remotely.